# class/struct design; inheritance vs forward declaration

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, forward-declaration

I'm having trouble understanding when/if single/multiple inheritance should be used vs forward declaration & I'd like to get a better understanding of it in the following example. If someone could point me in the right direction, or explain differences between them, it would be much appreciatd.

Following is sample of data structure I'm dealing with;

There exists 1 Parent, 1 SubParent & many **different** Children types. ie there's many Children per SubParent per Parent. Some Children need access to other Children objects. Children will use similar functions to each other ie ParseSelf/Display/Save/Edit. If Children get changed (ie Edit/Save), also need to update data in SubParent, Parent & possibly other Children.

I'm wanting to know what would be best way to implement something like this? I've come up with two alternatives below. If more clarification/information is needed please let me know.

```
class SubParent;
class Children;

class Parent
{
    ...
    int iParent;
    SubParent *pSubParent;
};

class SubParent
{
    ...
    int iSubParent;
    std::list<Children> childrenList;
};

class Children
{
    ...
    int iChild;
    int ChildType;
    char *pData;
};
```

versus;

```
class Parent
{
    ...
    int iParent;
};

class SubParent : public Parent
{
    ...
    int iSubParent;
};

class Children : public SubParent
{
    ...
    int iChild;
    int ChildType;
    char *pData;
};
```

Thank you.

EDIT:
Main job of Parent; maintains information about file ie location of SubParent, SubParent size, total size of all data including self.
Main job of SubParent; contains information about Children ie size & location of Children.
Both Parent/SubParent don't really do much else except keep these items upto date.

Comment: You're talking about inheritance vs. **composition.** You haven't given us enough information about what these classes should do, but your first approach is probably better.

Comment: @Beta I'll edit my question to add extra info around that.

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do. Before you write any class or interface, **always** write sample usage code in main first.

Comment: I don't see anything to suggest that `Children` in any way "is a" `SubParent`, or a `Parent`, so I don't see why inheritance would even be under consideration. If `SubParent` is supposed to contain a `std::list` of `Children`, inheritance won't be a substitute for this. Just seems like a very odd case. On the other hand, if you find yourself needing a member like `ChildType`, this may be an indication that polymorphism may be a better solution for this part. Further, you can avoid the forward declaration in the first example by just defining your classes in reverse order.

Comment: See [Prefer Composition over Inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend going with the first approach, with the following changes:

1. Add a member in `SubParent` that points to the `Parent`. This will allow you traverse the objects both ways.

   ```
   class SubParent
   {
       ...
       int iSubParent;
       Parent* parent;
       std::list<Children> childrenList;
   };
   ```
2. You should keep a list of `Children*` in `SubParent` instead of a list of `Chilren` if you are going to have different types of `Children`. If `Children` will never have any sub-classes, having a list of `Children` is good enough.
3. Add a pointer to the `SubParent` in `Children`. Again, that will allow you to traverse the objects both ways. Given a `Children`, you would be able to access its siblings through that pointer.

   ```
   class Children
   {
       ...
       int iChild;
       int ChildType;
       SubParent* subParent;
       char *pData;
   };
   ```

Comment: Would this way (ie use of pointers) still be necessary if classes were in reverse order instead of using forward declaration?

Comment: @ReturnVoid I didn't follow that question.

Comment: @R Sahu never mind, after re-reading your post a few times I figured it out.